# Solution to avoid deep copying in C#

Tags: c#

I have a variable `var1` which is a customized class that contains a single list of strings. I have another variable `var2` which is a list of classes like `var1`.

What I am aiming to do is I need to iterate over `var2`, class by class and instantiate `AddRange` to combine `var1s` list of string with `var2`'s `i`th class's own list of string. This is done independently, meaning that `var1`'s list of strings stays the same at each iteration. Only at each iteration will its list of string be combined with that of `var2`'s list of string, but after this iteration, it must revert back to the original. The problem is that I cant get this to work. Each time i add an string, it doesn't revert back.

I've tried making a deep copy and at the end of each iteration setting the intermediate clone class to null. Any ideas?

Below is a rough "PeudoCode"

```
public void combineString(CustomClass var1)
{
    // var2 is a class variable that contains a list of CustomClass

    List<CustomClass> finalized = new List<CustomClass>();

    for (int i = 0; i < var2.Count; i++)
    {

            CustomClass tmpVar = (CustomClass)var1.Clone();
            tmpVar.addString(var2[i].StringSet);  //each Custom class has a stringSet which is a list of strings


            // .....Do some analysis of the strings of tmpVar
            // if it passes the analysis add tmpVar in to finalize list
            // none of the other components should change

            if (pass analysis)
            {
                finalized.Add(tmpVar);

            }
            tmpVar = null;

    }

    // When the loop is done, the 'finalized' variable is a list of 
    // CustomClass but then each element inside finalized contains the same string set. 


    Console.WriteLine("Done");

}
```

Comment: yes, i am working on it! sorry!

Comment: Sounds to me that you can do this using *functional programming*.

Comment: LOL, yea, i come from a functional programming language, but then its too slow so writing it in C#

Answer (score 0):

So, `var1` must be unchanged. Either combine the strings into the other `var1`, or if that one must too be left as is, use a new list all together. I see no need to bother with cloning.

Comment: `var1` is a class in itself, and I need its components to stay intact throughout.

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically have to concatenate two lists of strings in a single string without touching the strings themselves.

Would something like this do for you?

`string concatenated = var1.Concat(var2[i].StringSet).Aggregate((item1, item2) => item1 + item2);`

`Aggregate` iterates over an IEnumerable and returns the concatenation of all its items.